# Installing packages to Anaconda Environments

Tags: python, anaconda

I've been having an issue with Anaconda, on two separate Windows machines.

I've downloaded and installed Anaconda. I know the commands, how to install libraries, I've even installed tensorflow-gpu (which works). I also use Jupyter notebook and I'm quite familiar with it by this point.

The issue:
For some reason, when I create new environments and install libraries to that environment... it ALWAYS installs them to (base). Whenever I  try to run code in a jupyter notebook that is located in an environment other than (base), it can't find any of the libraries I need... because it's installing them to (base) by default.

I always ensure that I've activated the correct environment before installing any libraries. But it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Can anyone help me with this... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you using conda or pip to install packages? are you sure you're using the pip that is installed in your environment when installing? what commands are you using to do the install?

Comment: Have you created the environemnt in Command Prompt/Shell and followed this https://gist.github.com/arsho/3b71a89867a74fee776aa7806456e0fd ?

Comment: I've tried both the pip and conda install commands, but I'm still experiencing the same problem. All packages are installed to base, even after activating and environment. It's very odd.

Comment: please add the exact list of commands you use to reproduce your problem....  are you sure that your notebook is connected to the correct python environment? (i.e. report the output of     `import sys
print(sys.executable)`   )

Comment: I think you're onto something. My result is this: C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\python.exe
Doesn't seem to be pointing to my environment. How can I change this?

Comment: I want it to point to C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\python.exe

Comment: ... in case you started the notebook from the console via first `avtivate tensorflow-gpu` and then `jupyter notebook`, this should actually happen automatically...   if you don't tell us the exact order of commands that you use to start your notebook-server it is a bit hard to tell what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of fixed my problem. It is to do with launching Jupyter notebook.

After switching environment via command prompt... the command 'jupyter notebook' runs jupyter notebook via the default python environment, regardless.

However, if I switch environments via anaconda navigator and launch jupyter notebook from there, it works perfectly.

Maybe I'm missing a command via the prompt?

Comment: again if you don't tell the commands you are using, it's hard to tell if they are correct